# Homotopy classes of self-maps on L(2,1)#L(3,1)

Tags: algebraic-topology

How to classify continuous self maps on $L(2,1)\# L(3,1)$ up to homotopy? Here $L(2,1)$ and $L(3,1)$ are lens spaces.

The reason for considering this manifold is that its fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\ast \mathbb{Z}_{3}$ which is isomorphic to ${\rm PGL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$, so that its elements can be written as matrices.

I am also interested in the homotopy classification of maps between any two closed oriented 3-manifolds.

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Is there any reason you expect that the self-maps *can* be classified? I would be surprised if the general problem is tractable.

Comment: I expect this only because this is a simple reducible 3-manifold @Mike Miller.